# using Observable from different components

Tags: angular, observable

I have a text box in the parent component and in parent I have an observable and as I enter alphabates in the input box by observable it should emit values and it should subscribe it in the child means the alphabets I enter in the parent component input box should be displayed in the child components

I want to do only using observable , no use of subject , services .

Comment: For this use case, you should pass in the data from the parent to the child component using an `@Input()`

Answer (score 1):

parent

```
// parent.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  template: `
    <input [formControl]="inputControl" />
    <app-child [data]="data$ | async"></app-child>
  `
})
export class ParentComponent {
  inputControl = new FormControl();
  data$: Observable<string>;

  constructor() {
    this.data$ = this.inputControl.valueChanges;
  }
}
```

child

```
// child.component.ts
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  template: `
    <div>
      Data from parent: {{ data }}
    </div>
  `
})
export class ChildComponent {
  @Input() data: string;
}
```

Make sure to import ReactiveFormsModule in your module to use FormControl.